# Join the table valued function in the query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one table vwuser. I want join this table with the table valued function fnuserrank(userID). So I need to cross apply with table valued function:

```
SELECT *
FROM vwuser AS a
CROSS APPLY fnuserrank(a.userid)
```

For each userID it generates multiple records. I only want the last record for each empid that does not have a Rank of Term(inated).  How can I do this?

Data:

```
HistoryID empid  Rank  MonitorDate
1          A1     E1    2012-8-9
2          A1     E2    2012-9-12 
3          A1     Term  2012-10-13
4          A2     E3     2011-10-09
5          A2     TERM   2012-11-9
```

From this 2nd record and 4th record must be selected.

Comment: What criteria are you using to decide "last record"?

Comment: There is one monitordate colmn, it must be maximum

Comment: I have also given data in my question and what I want

Comment: Wouldn't you want the 3rd and 4th records, since the MonitorDate for 3 is in October, and the second record's date is only September?

Comment: No, I want only 2nd and 4th record. This is because I dont want terminated records. I want records before this. i.e last active records

Comment: I did not realize you didn't want terminated records, I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: Because actually I want latest active rank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use this Common Table Expression ([CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) to determine the latest record by MonitorDate that doesn't have a Rank of 'Term':

```
WITH EmployeeData AS
(
   SELECT *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empId, ORDER BY MonitorDate DESC) AS RowNumber
   FROM vwuser AS a
   CROSS APPLY fnuserrank(a.userid)
   WHERE Rank != 'Term'
)
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeData AS ed
WHERE ed.RowNumber = 1;
```

**Note:** The statement before this CTE will need to end in a semi-colon.  Because of this, I have seen many people write them like `;WITH EmployeeData AS...`

Comment: Actually, I don't think you *have* to use a CTE. You could just use a nested `SELECT` like `SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT a,b,c FROM xyz) t1`.  However, the `ROW_NUMBER()` statement does require SQL Server 2005 or higher. Edit: As does `APPLY`, I believe.

Comment: @BaconBits You are correct, you do not have to use a CTE. I prefer how they look over nested selects though, which is why I use them in my answers when the OP Tags SQL Server 2005+ (either option will function the same in this case)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to play with this.  Having trouble mocking your schema on sqlfiddle.

```
Select bar.*
from 
(
SELECT *
FROM vwuser AS a
CROSS APPLY fnuserrank(a.userid)
where rank != 'TERM'
) foo
left join 
(
SELECT *
FROM vwuser AS b
CROSS APPLY fnuserrank(b.userid)
where rank != 'TERM'
) bar
on foo.empId = bar.empId
  and foo.MonitorDate > bar.MonitorDate
where bar.empid is null
```

I always need to test out left outers on dates being higher.  The way it works is you do a left outer.  Every row EXCEPT one per user has row(s) with a higher monitor date.  That one row is the one you want.  I usually use an example from my code, but i'm on the wrong laptop.  to get it working you can select foo.*, bar.* and look at the results and spot the row you want and make the condition correct.

You could also do this, which is easier to remember

```
SELECT *
FROM vwuser AS a
CROSS APPLY fnuserrank(a.userid)
) foo
join 
(
select empid, max(monitordate) maxdate
FROM vwuser AS b
CROSS APPLY fnuserrank(b.userid)
 where rank != 'TERM'
) bar
on foo.empid = bar.empid
and foo.monitordate = bar.maxdate
```

I usually prefer to use set based logic over aggregate functions, but whatever works.  You can tweak it also by caching the results of your TVF join into a table variable.

EDIT: 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/613e4/17 - I mocked up your TVF here.  Apparently sqlfiddle didn't like "go".

```
select foo.*, bar.*
from 
(
SELECT f.*
FROM vwuser AS a
join fnuserrank f
  on a.empid = f.empid
where rank != 'TERM'
) foo
left join 
(
SELECT f1.empid [barempid], f1.monitordate [barmonitordate]
FROM vwuser AS b
join fnuserrank f1
  on b.empid = f1.empid
where rank != 'TERM'
) bar
on foo.empId = bar.barempid
  and foo.MonitorDate > bar.barmonitordate
where bar.barempid is  null
```

Comment: BTW - you can you "GO" (all caps) in SQL Fiddle (for SQL Server queries) - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e45d/1

Comment: How odd that capitalization would matter for that.

Comment: Yeah, I could relax the case requirements, I suppose.  Maybe I'll add that to my to-do list.  My impression was that people always used GO in all caps, so it hasn't come up before.

Comment: That requires pressing SHIFT.  An entire extra key press!  I'm way too lazy to do that :)  Hey, big props for sqlfiddle!

Comment: Good news, Brian - as a result of our chat, I've fixed the code to no longer be case-sensitive. GO, Go, go, and gO - Thanks!